# Cannot save form data having boolean attribute with API Platform

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm using Symfony4 and API Pltaform, the API Platform works fine.

I'm tring to save data with FormType and **Http Client component** but if the form have boolean attribute I get this error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO book (isbn, title, description, author, publication_date, active, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["ISBN 2-7654-1005-8", "Test book", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt u", "Alex", "2020-01-10 16:43:53", null, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'active' cannot be null

**But if I remove the attribute "active"** from the form , the data are saved well in the database.

This is the dump of **$data** withch contains the Form data:

[image]

and this is the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="admin_book_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request)
{

    $book = new Book();

    $form = $this->createForm(BookType::class, $book);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
    if ($form->isSubmitted() and $form->isValid()) {

       $data = $form->getData();

        $this->client->request('POST', $this->getParameter('base_url').'/books', array(
            'json' => $data
        ));

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_book_index');

    }

    return $this->render('admin/book/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Comment: The entity book is marked with ApiResource annotation and I send data to api via HttpClient symfony component. The api platform works and if I remove the attribute "active" from the form , the data are saved in the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() and $form->isValid()) {

        $data = [];
        foreach ($form->all() as $field) {
            $name = $field->getName();
            $value = $field->getData();

            $data[$name] = $value;
        }

        $this->client->request('POST', $this->getParameter('base_url').'/books', array(
            'json' => $data
        ));

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_book_index');

    }
```